# IPython-Parallel: Dict literal missing in parallel map

Tags: python, dictionary, ipython, ipython-parallel

I encountered this problem that any `dict` literal involved in ipyparallel `map` is missing and becomes `{}` in the output result.

This problem does not impact dict items added via the `update` method and dict constructors.

To reproduce the problem, you may spin up a cluster with a `direct view` called, say `dview`. The below code was tested in IPython with Python 3.4 (both client and engine).

```
dview.map(lambda x: {'label': x*2}, range(4)}
```

It will return `[{}, {}, {}, {}]`, when you expect the `label` key to appear in the dict.

The same problem happens as well in the following situations:

- Normal function declaration
- Dict literal used as an intermediate value (even as the argument to `update`)

Comment: Just realized: This is only reproducible using a remote cluster. Spun up `ipcluster` on local machine, it works fine. Even if I execute `ipython` then `rc = Client()` on the very machine hosting the controller, the above code runs properly.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this applies to your python 3.4 problem, but when I run your code on python 2.7.9, the `map` method generates an async object and not a dictionary. In order to get a dictionary using the `map` method, I have to use list comprehension to iterate through the async object. The `map_sync` method however works just fine.

Here's a code snippet if you'd like to try it on your remote cluster (inserting appropriate json file):

```
from IPython.parallel import Client

c = Client()
dview = c[:]

smap = dview.map_sync(lambda x: {'label': x*2}, range(4))
print(smap) #gives dict

amap = dview.map(lambda x: {'label': x*2}, range(4))
print(amap) #produces async obj

amap_dict = [r for i,r in enumerate(amap)]
print(amap_dict) #gives dict
```

More info on async objects here : https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/parallel/asyncresult.html#map-results-are-iterable